# Windows 8 changes screen brightness between profiles

Tags: windows-8, laptop, battery

When switching between power profiles in windows 8, the screen brightness changes to the profiles last brightness setting.

I often switch between balanced and high performance profiles. This changes my brightness setting to whatever it was the last time I used the other profile.

Is there a way that I can change battery profiles *without* affecting my screen brightness level? I would like that one setting to be independent of the battery profile and simply remain where I set it.

Comment: I'm not sure if you can make it independent option, but you can set brightness settings for both profiles in the power options, set them the same for every profile.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it's not possible. There's no one brightness setting that suits all situations, so no matter what you set it at in the power plan settings (even if they're all the same) it'll be wrong sometime. Each plan actually remembers your last setting, but that setting isn't usually current by the time I switch profiles again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can edit and adjust the brightness for "Balanced" and "High Performance" profiles using the options "Adjust Plan Settings" option. You configure your convenient brightness on the profiles such that even you switch between the profiles , the brightness remains as configure[image]ed.

Comment: You can set all plans to default to the same brightness, but I might be using a brightness above or below that at any given time. Also each plan remembers your last setting, but I'm often on a different brightness level when I set that power plan again later. It irks me when it switches to the previous setting on me suddenly.

Comment: @davidparks21 Looks like this answer doesn't actually answer your question, so you should unaccept it

Comment: It was as close as I've ever found and I didn't want to leave the loose ends. If I see a better answer pop up I'll move it over.